# Core dumped upon realloc text above 26 chars c

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I need to comunicate with my own protocol a server and some telescopes sending data. After the communication is done, I split the message to know what case it is. Connection and disconnection work fine, but splitting data gives me core dumped (**realloc(): invalid next size**).

Connection sends this message: `0x01[]10[Telescope1]`
Disconnection sends this message: `0x02[]10[Telescope1]`
Sending data sends this message: `0x03[METADATA]22[.txt&15&someRandomDate]`

I intend to split those messages into **type** (0x03), **header** (METADATA), **lenght of data field** (22) and **data** (.txt&15&someRandomDate).

After some testing I reached the conclusion that is due to the size of the string. To debug, when sending data I used the connection message instead and splitting would work fine (each filed returned correctly).

Then I would gradually change it char by char to what it's suposed to split and would split this message fine `0x03[METADA]10[Telescope1]` (size 26), but not `0x03[METADAT]10[Telescope1]` (size 27). On the second case it would output what follows:

```
string to split: 0x03[METADAT]10[Telescope1]
copying type 0
realloc of size 1
copying type x
realloc of size 2
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So it would go as far as to read 0x and them go core dumped.
Also would core dumped if I made the connection or disconnection string larges than 27 chars by adding random text inside the message.

Here is my code for splitting the string. It's quite bad since I always struggle with mallocs and reallocs, so sorry in advance.

```
Data read_data (char* string){
printf("string to split: %s\n", string);
Data d;
int i = 0;
char *aux = (char *) malloc(1);

while (string[i] != '[' || string[i] == '\0'){

    printf("copying type %c\n", string[i]);
    printf("realloc of size %d\n", (i + 1));
    aux = (char *) realloc(aux, (i + 1));
    //here also tried aux = (char *) realloc(aux, (i + 1) * sizeof(char*)); didn't work
    strcpy(&aux[i], &string[i]);
    i++;
}
aux[i] = '\0';
d.type = aux[3];

i++;

int j = 0;
aux = (char *) malloc(1);
while (string[i] != ']' || string[i] == '\0'){
    printf("copying header %c\n", string[i]);
    aux = (char *) realloc(aux, j + 1);
    strcpy(&aux[j], &string[i]);
    i++;
    j++;
}
aux[j] = '\0';
d.header = aux;

i++;

j = 0;
aux = (char *) malloc(1);
while (string[i] != '[' || string[i] == '\0'){
    printf("copying size %c\n", string[i]);
    aux = (char *) realloc(aux, j + 1);
    strcpy(&aux[j], &string[i]);
    i++;
    j++;
}
aux[j] = '\0';
d.length = atoi(aux);

i++;
j = 0;
aux = (char *) malloc(1);
while (string[i] != ']' || string[i] == '\0'){
    printf("copying data %c\n", string[i]);
    aux = (char *) realloc(aux, j + 1);
    strcpy(&aux[j], &string[i]);
    i++;
    j++;
}
aux[j] = '\0';
d.data = aux;
return d;
}
```

How can I fix this? Why does it work fine if it's a shorter string?

**EDIT**: As Spikatrix pointed out, if I use `aux[i] = string[i];` instead of `strcpy(&aux[i], &string[i]);` works fine

Comment: Try `aux[i] = string[i];` instead of `strcpy(&aux[i], &string[i]);`

Comment: @Spikatrix bro, you're a genius. works fine. thank you very much!

Comment: Have you learned `for()` loops yet? Use them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message *realloc(): invalid next size* basically says that the heap has been corrupted (before the `realloc()` call). So the problem is not *realloc* but other code.

And at first glance, the following statement is the culprit:

```
strcpy(&aux[i], &string[i]);
```

You probably want to copy a single character to the end of *aux*. But it does something completely different. It copies *string* – starting at position *i* and up to the end of *string* – to *aux* starting at position *i*. However, *aux* is only *i + 1* characters long. So this operation writes outside the allocated string and corrupts the heap.

Better drop the entire code. It's unnecessarily complex and inefficient. Use *strchr* to locate the relevant characters (opening and closing brackets). Then you know the position and can easily copy the relevant substring.